# How to dynamically concat a block of byte stream from http response in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, http, httprequest, concatenation

So,

I want to send a stream of bytes to the browser(for example a pdf) so he can show it to the user.

```
if (bytesToRead == -1) {
                bytesToRead = (int)fullPathFile.length();}
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesToRead];
            int bytesRead = -1;     
            if((inputFileInputStream != null) && ((bytesRead = inputFileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)){ 

                if (codec.equals("base64")) {
                    String streamLength = Base64.encodeBytes(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);
                    response.setContentLength(streamLength.length());
                    outputFileOutputStream.write(Base64.encodeBytes(buffer, 0, bytesToRead).getBytes());

                } else {
                    outputFileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);
                }
            }
            inputFileInputStream.close();
            outputFileOutputStream.flush();
            outputFileOutputStream.close();
```

At the moment it works with option -1 to get the stream of byte in one go but I want to send 2kb lets says. I understand that for that I need to send multiple 2kb replies and I have to concatenate them in the javascript code. But, how do I do that ?

Comment: What javascript? This is java code.

Comment: Why are you using javascript to consume the response for a pdf when the browser already has the capability?

Comment: @Stultuske: this is the java code, but I ask about the javascript implementation.

Comment: @Stultuske I saw that as well.  I'm assuming there's javascript somewhere, but maybe the poster doesn't know the difference.

Comment: @MadConan: I will do multiple operations(including file download) with various other formats.

Comment: I do know the difference. This is the java backend where I send as a http response a byte stream [] to the browser. Then, in javascript I made a page for testing where I set the header application/pdf;base64. Now, all I want is to send it in multiple parts not in one-go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an for() where I incremented the offset.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your arrays using concat()...

```
var allBytes = [];

for (byteArray in allByteArray){
    allBytes = allBytes.concat(byteArray);
}
```

But if you want to join multiple PDF pages it wont work...

Comment: I send base64 byte stream in parts and I merge it in javascript. What does that have to do with the pages ?

Comment: What are you using to generate the pdf byteArray?? i think will be easy to make a multipage pdf first and then send to `javascript` in just one byteArray

Comment: I set the header of the browser, either in the java code or in javascript as application/pdf;base64 and the browser loads the pdf plugin.

Comment: And what is that alllByteArray ?